# How do I set GODEBUG environment variables in Golang so I can use godebug with net/http

Tags: go

I want to step through my program using [Godebug](https://github.com/mailgun/godebug%22godebug%22). However because I'm using net/http I get errors such as:

```
/home/heath/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:45:2: could not import golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack" in any of:
    /home/heath/go/src/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (from $GOROOT)
```

/x/net/http2/hpack does exist in my GOPATH but in ~heath/go/src/golang.org ... not golang_org (not sure what's happening there)

I have read that this error occurs because godebug doesn't support http2 yet (can't find source).

I have tried to disable http2server and http2client by setting the GODEBUG env both in init() and on the command line. I have also confirmed that these settings are being set by doing a fmt.Println("GODEBUG", os.Getenv("GODEBUG"). As per instructions located [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

```
GODEBUG=http2client=0  # disable HTTP/2 client support
GODEBUG=http2server=0  # disable HTTP/2 server support
```

My simple code example to replicate the error is:

```
  package main

  import "fmt"
  import "net/http"
  import "os"

  func init() {

      os.Setenv("GODEBUG", "http2server=0,http2client=0")

  }

  func main() {

      fmt.Println("GODEBUG", os.Getenv("GODEBUG"))

      _ = "breakpoint"
      fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
      http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
  }

godebug run example.go
```

I am running Go version:

go version go1.7 linux/amd64

Comment: Check your `$GOROOT/src/vendor/` folder if there is a `golang_org` folder.

Comment: Yes, that directory exists.    ls $GOROOT/src/vendor/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack/
encode.go  encode_test.go  hpack.go  hpack_test.go  huffman.go  tables.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the correct way to do things. But I copied the http2 package from my vendor directory under $GOROOT/src/vendor to the src directory under my $GOPATH/src.

If anyone has any further input on the correct way to reference vendor directories please add your thoughts. Just putting my workaround here in case someone else comes across the same issue.

Edit: Actually a 'nicer' way to do things was to do an ln -s ..src/vender/github_org to ../src/github_org